# Precision in Integrals and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy

I have a simplest code for NDSolve, the problem is I am dividing two small numbers, the denominator is so small that it gives me infinity as an answer, how can I increase the precision to get a reasonable answer.
N1 = 100000;
th =   [Pi]/4;

```
s0 = 0.01 + 0.007 Sin[th];


h = 0.3;
nst0 =
  NDSolve[{
    
    (x (1 - x))/(2 N1) D[T0[x], x, x] +  
      s0  x (1 - x)  (x + h (1 - 2 x )) D[T0[x], x] == -\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(x\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-\ \ N1\)\ s0\ a\ \((a\  + \ 
            2\ h\ \((1 - a)\))\)\)] \[DifferentialD]a\)\)/\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-\ 
          N1\)\ s0\ a\ \((a\  + \ 
           2\ h\ \((1 - a)\))\)\)] \[DifferentialD]a\)\)  ,
    T0[0.000000001] == 0, T0[.99999999] == 0 
    
    }, {T0}, {x, 0.000000001, .99999999}];
T0e = T0 /. First@nst0;



T0e[1/(2 N1)]/(\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(1/\((2\ N1)\)\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-\ \ N1\)\ s0\ a\ \((a\  + \ 
        2\ h\ \((1 - a)\))\)\)] \[DifferentialD]a\)\)/\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-\ 
       N1\)\ s0\ a\ \((a\  + \ 
        2\ h\ \((1 - a)\))\)\)] \[DifferentialD]a\)\))
```

Comment: Please post ML code not boxes. An integral is specified by e.g.: `Integrate[some expression of x, {x,xmin,xmax}]`

Comment: You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful for formatting code.

Answer (score 1):

**improved answer**

Here I'll show how to solve your problem which is singular for `x==0` and `x==1` and illscaled for `N1>>1`

First the differential equation

```
s0 = 0.01 + 0.007/1000 Sin[th] // Rationalize;
h = 0.3 // Rationalize;
th = Pi/4;
ode[N1_] := (x (1 - x))/(2 N1) D[T0[x], x, x] +  
             s0  x (1 - x)  (x + h (1 - 2 x )) D[T0[x], x] == -Integrate[
         E^(-  N1 s0 a (a + 2 h (1 - a))), {a, 0, x}]/
       Integrate[E^(- N1 s0 a (a + 2 h (1 - a))), {a, 0, 1}]
```

solution of the ode `N1=10000`

```
T = With[{e = 10^-10, N1 = 10000}, 
NDSolveValue[{ode[N1],
         T0[e] == 0, T0[1 - e] == 0}, {T0}, {x, e, 1 - e} ][[1]] ] 

Plot[T[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

That solves your problem in principle.

I don't have more time to elaborate the case `N1=100000` which needs numerical  finetuning concerning WorkingPrecision&Co ...

**case `N1=100000`**

Thanks to the answer @Dominic ,which let  me to the idea using `$MaxExtraPrecision = 100` . `Block`instead of `With` (don't know why it's necessary) evaluates to

```
T = Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100, e = 10^-10, N1 = 100000}, 
NDSolveValue[{ode[N1], T0[e] == 0, T0[1 - e] == 0}, {T0}, {x, e,1 - e}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 35][[1]]] 
Plot[T[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Ulrich's code above, adjust MaxStepSize, MaxSteps and WorkingPrecision as needed.  This is the code for N1=30000 on a 3.5 GHz machine.  Note I set up the problem for arbitrary precision arithmetic (use rational numbers for constants) and then set working precision to 25:

```
th = Pi/4;
s0 = 1/100 + 7/1000 Sin[th]
h = 3/10

ode[N1_] := (x (1 - x))/(2 N1) D[T0[x], x, x] + 
   s0 x (1 - x) (x + h (1 - 2 x)) D[T0[x], x] == -Integrate[
     E^(-N1 s0 a (a + 2 h (1 - a))), {a, 0, x}]/
   Integrate[E^(-N1 s0 a (a + 2 h (1 - a))), {a, 0, 1}]

AbsoluteTiming[
T=With[{e=10^-10,N1=30000},NDSolveValue[{ode[N1],T0[e]==0,T0[1-e]==0},{T0},{x,e,1-e},
MaxStepSize->1/20000,
MaxSteps->1000000,
WorkingPrecision->25][[1]]];
]

Out[61]= {26.3717,Null}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, good idea to use  `Rationalize` . But further improvement  towards  `N1 ==100000` stands out...

Comment: See my modified answer (case N1=100000)